# Fluent NHibernate table naming convention not working

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, conventions

I have the following convention which I load into my FNH config

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention, IClassConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IClassInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.TableName, Is.Not.Set);
    }

    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        var tableName = instance.EntityType.Name.Pluralise();

        instance.Table(tableName);
    }
}
```

I do not specify table names on *any* of my mappings, yet this convention is not applied. I'm using Fluent NHibernate 1.4.1.1. Can anyone spot anything I might have done wrong?

**UPDATE**

The conventions are loaded in the following manner:

```
public static NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration BuildConfiguration()
{
    var connectionStringName = "mydb";
    return Fluently.Configure(new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration())
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
                      .MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connectionStringName))
                      .Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>()
                      .AdoNetBatchSize(50))
        .Mappings(m =>
        {
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Profile>();
            m.FluentMappings.Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always(), DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue(), DynamicInsert.AlwaysTrue());
            m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<HiLoConvention>();
        })
        .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, typeof(ManagedWebSessionContext).AssemblyQualifiedName))
        .ExposeConfiguration(HiLoConvention.CreateScript)
        .ExposeConfiguration(RunSchemaUpdate)
        .BuildConfiguration();
}
```

All conventions sit in the same assembly and namespace as the HiLoConvention referenced above in the .AddFromAssembly() method call.

**UPDATE 2:**

The problem is in the Accept() method, because if I remove this method (and also the IClassConventionAcceptance interface from the class declaration) then the convention is applied. I have also tried this expectation to no avail

```
criteria.Expect(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TableName))
```

The original code worked with Fluent 1.2.1...

Comment: How are you loading this convention? Could you share that code?

Comment: @Suhas, certainly. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but perhaps this can help someone else:

I assume you wanted to set the convention on each entity, unless a table name was specified explicitly in the map. So to achieve that, you can simply do the following:

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        var tableName = instance.EntityType.Name.Pluralise();

        instance.Table(tableName);
    }
}
```

This will apply the convention on all entities, unless TableName was specified explicitly in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
m.FluentMappings.ConventionDiscovery.AddFromAssemblyOf<HiLoConvention>()
```

in place of

```
m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<HiLoConvention>()
```

Comment: What assembly is ConventionDiscovery part of? This doesn't build for me.

Comment: The conventions are being picked up, by the way. I can debug and see that the Accept() method runs. But Apply() doesn't.